# Create svn structure in svn repository

Tags: tortoisesvn, assembla

I get repository where main folder is folder of solution. I want create folders trunk, branches, tags, etc. This repository is on Assembla.
I'm using windows 7 and newest SVN Tortoise. Is it some simple way to reconstruct this repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you want, but why not make the folders and then move the rest of the files where they belong? Sure, it will mess with the history a bit (old deleted files won't show up in the new folders), but that's rarely a problem.